# Xcode Count of like items in Array

Tags: arrays, xcode, count, nsarray

I have a list of years in an Array. Which I would like to output as a list of the counts.

For example:

```
NSArray *years = @[@"2012", @"2014", @"2009", @"2014", @"2010", @"2014", @"2009"];
```

I am looking to turn this into something like this in a Dictionary.

```
Year = 2012, Count = 1
Year = 2014, Count = 3
Year = 2009, Count = 2
Year = 2010, Count = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Use NSCountedSet http://stackoverflow.com/a/7606138/2458651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *years = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2012", @"2014", @"2009", @"2014", @"2010", @"2014", @"2009", nil];
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:years];

for (id item in set)
{
   NSLog(@"Name=%@, Count=%lu", item, (unsigned long)[set countForObject:item]);
}
```

I suggest you invest some time into reading a book about Cocoa's features.

Comment: Thanks, I was using NSCountedSet but I must have had something wrong in my for statement. The NSArray was just for example, the array is actually being created programatically.

Comment: @JasonBestor I'm glad you have it solved :) let me know if you have any other questions!